# FitnessActivities.getName(int i) method is deprecated, what method to use instead?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In the following library:
 `com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.8.0`

In the following class: `com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessActivities`

There is this method: `public static java.lang.String getName(int i)`

However, in the library `com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.2.0` the above mentioned method is removed.

What method to use instead of the above mentioned method?

Comment: This is an educated guess based on the documentation, but assuming you are getting a `DataPoint` object type sent to your callback, could it be something like `dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).asActivity()`? Didn't want to make an answer just yet as I'm just taking a guess, not testing it. Let me know

Comment: I dont know much about this api but there is a method getMIMEType() 
maybe it might help you at this link 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessActivities#public-methods

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us some code? I assume that you have a variable with value X and you want to perform some actions according to this value. If that is the case, I will do that with a switch statement:

```
switch(myFitnessValue) {
case FitnessActivities.AEROBICS:
    doAerobics();
break;

case FitnessActivities.BIKING:
    doBiking();
break;

case FitnessActivities.WALKING:
    doWalking();
break;

default:
    doNothing();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to make switch statement with 100 constants from FitnessActivities. Plus  what would happen if they add one more ?

Comment: If you don't want to make 100 switch statements then you will need to make 100 if statements. Lets say that the method is not deprecated, according to the activity name, you will need to perform a different action.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method below. I have used it with argument 9 which stands for aerobics.

```
zza.getName(9)
```

Do not forget to import the class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.zza;
```